# Is Susy SEMANTIC?

Tags: semantics, susy-compass

There are many Grid frameworks. However there are just a few, which are responsive and at the same time semantic.

The [Semantic Grid System](http://semantic.gs/) is one these Grid systems.

I just wonder if [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) is also SEMANTIC?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Susy is just as semantic as The Semantic Grid System.

That said, the term "semantic grid system" is misleading. No grid system is semantic, because grids are only about layout, applied to HTML markup. Your HTML markup *can* be semantic, but that's all up to you and your grid system cannot turn non-semantic HTML into semantic HTML. What people call "a semantic grid system" is only a grid system that does not require you to add additional non-semantic classes to your HTML markup.